# Is there a way to import numbers from another sheet every 'x' hours?

Tags: google-sheets, importrange

I want to link two spreadsheets with IMPORTRANGE, let's say A with B. B is the source. I want A to import numbers from B every 6 hours, because the numbers in B are constantly moving and since the sheet is really big, it would slow down sheet A.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: didn't try it out, but a IFTTT date&time plus google drive seems promising

Comment: Do you need to run the update in the background, i.e. when you're not viewing the spreadsheet?

Comment: yeah. data is constantly being fed into.

Comment: You can do this with Google Apps Script (needs JavaScript knowledge). Also, you could find this useful:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20444102/google-apps-script-is-there-a-way-to-keep-two-sheets-synchronized

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `IMPORTRANGE` function does not seem to cache its results, so it will refresh whenever the source spreadsheet changes.

But we can circumvent this by writing our own function:

```
function customImportRange(spreadsheetUrl, rangeStr, timestamp) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(spreadsheetUrl);
  var range = sheet.getRange(rangeStr);
  return range.getValues();
}
```

Install this function by clicking *Tools → Editor*, paste the code, and click the *Run* button. This will popup a dialog asking you to give the script permission to run.

The script does exactly the same as `IMPORTRANGE`, but, being a Google Apps Scripts function, Google Spreadsheets will cache its results, and *not* fetch any new data as long as the parameters to the function are unchanged.

That means that we can change the `timestamp` parameter every 6 hours to trigger a refetch, which again means that we need a formula that generates a new value every 6 hours.

Given that we put `=NOW()` in cell `B1`, and the following formula in cell `C1`:

```
=DATEVALUE(B1) * 10 + ROUNDUP(HOUR(B1) / 6)
```

Cell `C1` now displays a number that changes every 6 hours, meaning we can use it as input to our function. Put the following in cell `A2`:

```
=customImportRange("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qFryUlGfGT8dp_lx9sSE_7suCV0t8cAg9btM1AOPnSI/edit#gid=0", "'Custom function'!A4:F6", C1)
```

The parameters are:

1. The full URL to the source spreadsheet
2. The range notation for the data you want to fetch
3. The cache key

I have put up [an example spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OYVYEFIkO61rCgZn7gGA57u4mxeMfr17Rl1LtB5CvnI/edit?usp=sharing) to demonstrate this, feel free to copy it for your own experimentation.

To have the spreadsheet update also when it is not opened in a browser, you should go to *File → Spreadsheet settings* and set *Recalculation* to *On change and every hour*.

Comment: Vidar. Thanks for the solution. I will try out your script.

Comment: According to [Change a spreadsheet's locale, time zone, recalculation, and language](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/58515?hl=en) the recalculation doesn't affect IMPORTRANGE as the article says that iMPORTRANGE is recalculated every 30 minutes. By the other hand, the new Google Sheets doesn't allow non-deterministic values as parameters. Is your script still working for you? (I'm not scanning the site for your answers, it "emerged" because a new answer was posted)

Comment: No, it seems you are right. It now gives an error saying that the non deterministic functions can't be used. I'll see if I can rework this answer to be compatible with the new Spreadsheets. Thanks for noticing!