# How can I select a subset of random elements from a list in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

**Example:**

Select two random elements from the list below. A chosen element should not be chosen twice.

[image]

Comment: How "random"? Could the same element be picked twice?

Comment: Very good point! Not twice. Please see my edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There *is* a `RANDOM` function in Google Sheets, and it could definitely be used here, but it would be a messy formula. I prefer writing these kind of things as scripts.

Click *Tools → Script Editor*, and paste this code:

```
function selectRandomElements(fromValueRows, count) {
  var pickedRows = []; // This will hold the selected rows
  for (var i = 0; i < count && fromValueRows.length > 0; i++) {
    var pickedIndex = getRandomInt(0, fromValueRows.length);
    // Pick the element at position pickedIndex, and remove it from fromValueRows. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice
    var pickedRow = fromValueRows.splice(pickedIndex, 1)[0]; 
    // Add the selected row to our result array
    pickedRows.push(pickedRow);
  }
  return pickedRows;
}

function getRandomInt(min, max) { // From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}

/* This is merely to test our function. It can be run directly from the script editor. Open View -> Log to see the results */
function testRandomElements() {
  var fromValues = [["Bob"], ["Jenny"], ["Alex"], ["Steven"], ["Monique"]];
  var result = selectRandomElements(fromValues, 2);
  Logger.log(result);
}
```

The function in the script basically takes a list of `values` and a `count` as inputs, and returns `count` randomly selected values.

This will give you access to a function `selectRandomElements`, which you can use from your spreadsheet, e.g.

```
=selectRandomElements(A2:A6; 2)
```

This will give you two random values from the `A2:A6` range.

See [the example spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1i0o1RgaKfu4xDCwGqQsPS3UkL-dzSq8EL8cOoeNmz7I/edit?usp=sharing) I have setup to demonstrate.

**Note**: The random selection will only happen once. That is, as long as the input data, and the formula, is the same, the two selected rows will be the same. If you want to rerun the selection at intervals, see [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/73868/21583) for a hint.

Answer (score 0):

I recently came across a similar issue to this. Instead of exactly 2 items, I wanted to select a random number of items from a list.

This is how I did it, selecting a random number of values from the range `A2:A6`:

```
=FILTER(A2:A6, ARRAYFORMULA( RANDARRAY(LEN(A2:A6),1) > 0.5) )
```

This can sometimes select no items and give an error, to catch that a give a default value `IFERROR` can be used. Below gives a default value of `""`.

```
=IFERROR( FILTER(A2:A6, ARRAYFORMULA( RANDARRAY(LEN(A2:A6),1) > 0.5) ), "")
```